# replace all occurences of characters that are not alphanumeric with a space

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
 $escapedStringBio = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", " ", $escapedStringBio);
```

I wanted to remove all occurences of special character, being that unicode char's etc and I want to replace that with space. However the code above still didn't do me well. Some strings with apostrophes still got in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post samples of such strings? Since your regex seems well, only need to add `u` modifier for utf-strings (also, you can omit `+` in your regex, it isn't necessary there)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: The `+` quantifier is usefull because there is only one replace for a group of characters.

Comment: @adit: What is initial value of `$escapedStringBio`?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is quite alright, tho characters like á are not actually word-characters, you can capture these like this: `/([a-z\W]+)/gi`

the `\W` matches any numeric character that is not a word character.

If you need to test more regexes I would strongly suggest using [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)